# How to refresh the disabled ListView

Tags: android, listview

I need help to refresh the `ListView` of disabled item. I've read a few articles, I gotta say I have no idea how to refresh the disabled item, therefore if you can give me a hand and post  with that additional desired code, it would be more than appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

I have this code in my Activity:

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        for (int i = 0; i <itemsList1.size(); i++) {
            if(i == position){ 
                view.setEnabled(false);
                view.setClickable(false);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));

                ItemsBean bean = new ItemsBean();
                bean.setInvNo(itemsList1.get(position).getInvNo());
                bean.setItemnNameDisplay(itemsList1.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                bean.setQuantityDisplay(itemsList1.get(position).getQuantityDisplay());
                bean.setProdnum(itemsList1.get(position).getProdnum());
                newlist.add(bean);
                adapter.getmethod(position);
            }
        }

        insertintodatabase(newlist);
        newlist.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }

});
```

This is my custom Adapter class I don't know where is fault but i need help to complete the project as am new to android

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    private int pos;
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    ArrayList<ItemsBean> newList = new ArrayList<ItemsBean>();
    ArrayList<ItemsBean> newListitems = new ArrayList<ItemsBean>();
    ArrayList<String> childList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> qtychildList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String parentobjid=null;
    PendingOrdersActitvity myactivity;

    public CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity kdsActitvity, ArrayList<ItemsBean> invoiceDataList) {
        this.ctx = kdsActitvity;
        this.newList = invoiceDataList;
        this.inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        pos = -1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return newList.size();
    }

    public void getmethod(int pos1) {
        pos = pos1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView qty, name, childText, qtyChild;

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        String item = null, qty = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.invoicelistadapter, null);
            holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
            holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            if(pos!=-1 && pos==position)
            {
                convertView.setEnabled(false);
                convertView.setClickable(false);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));

            }
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        //holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newList.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));

        parentobjid=newList.get(position).getParentobjectid();
        if(!parentobjid.isEmpty())
        {
            holder.name.setText("   " +newList.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
            holder.qty.setText("      "+String.valueOf(newList.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
            holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));

        } else {
            holder.name.setText(newList.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
            holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newList.get(position)
                    .getQuantityDisplay()));
            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `CustomAdapter` code too.

Comment: will u plzz help me Mr Neeraj

Comment: What happens if you click a row?

Comment: actually i have  list views attached to button , if i disabling item in list view and goes for another button ., if i come back to previous button the item which i disabled is not showing as disable item it is showing normal list

Comment: will u plzz help me

Answer (score 0):

call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() inside the listview ClickListener.

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

         @Override
         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {


         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             for (int i = 0; i <itemsList1.size(); i++) {
                 if(i == position){ 
                      view.setEnabled(false);
                      view.setClickable(false);
                      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));


                      ItemsBean bean=new ItemsBean();
                      bean.setInvNo(itemsList1.get(position).getInvNo());
                      bean.setItemnNameDisplay(itemsList1.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                      bean.setQuantityDisplay(itemsList1.get(position).getQuantityDisplay());
                      bean.setProdnum(itemsList1.get(position).getProdnum());
                      newlist.add(bean);
                      adapter.getmethod(position);
                 }

             insertintodatabase(newlist);
            newlist.clear();
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


return true;



         }

         });
```

Comment: then check itemsList1 values

Comment: sry i didnt understand wt u said

Answer (score 0):

The ListView is just a container.
Instead of enabling the single items, clear it and recreate it through your Adapter.

In fact the adapter just ties the ListView to an ArrayList of elements and represents into the ListView the "state" of the ArrayList.

Do not operate to ListView already created, but refresh the ArrayList and the ListView will be refreshed too!

Comment: no its project i want to enable it not to clear items

Answer (score 0):

use `notifydatasetchanged();`

Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself